# mt_rand  max value

Tags: php, unique-id

On the php documentation,i found this note:

> On both 32 and 64-bit systems (OS X and Linux), mt_getrandmax()
>   returns 2147483647

I have confirmed this using the simple function provided

```
function gethighest()
{
return mt_getrandmax();
}
$hello = gethighest();
echo '<b>'.$hello.'</b>';
```

I am using this snippet to generate a unique id

```
$number = mt_rand(163245,978534);
$unique_id = crypt($number);
echo md5($unique_id).'<br/>';
```

My question is,what does it mean to have a max value for mt_rand?.Will the ids begin to repeat once the max value is reached?.

Comment: Are you doing this just to generate a unique id? Does it have to be numeric?

Comment: Why are you using two different hash algorithms (`crypt()` and `md5()`) to get a hashed key? I would suggest that one is enough. You can also use `sha1()` which gives you a 40-char hexadecimal string with any input…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
$number = mt_rand(163245,978534);
```

means that the number generated will be between those 2 numbers, it will for as many times as you run it, generate a number between those 2 values.. No returned value will be outside that range. But yes, values can be repeated..

eg try it with mt_rand(1,5) and tell it to do it 20 times and output.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using uniqid? http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: What is the advantage of unique id function vs the mt_rand function?.

Comment: You do less work, and its guaranteed to return a unique id. Need more?

Answer (score 1):

If you intent to generate a unique ID, you should use [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php):

```
$unique_id = uniqid(microtime(true));
```